# torch translate to JAX for normalizing flow

Tags: python, pytorch, jax

Recently, I am learning normalizing flow. And my professor requests me to write it in Python JAX for a 3d modeling fitting. Let's start with a simple one. I followed the video: https://youtu.be/6u7o5--aYNc?si=Y4WvaO6m3OdvXM_r  . I think I got a good result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJOau.png)
But my z distribution is not like that shows on the video.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7EIt.png)
From the video, the z distribution should be kind of randomly set between 0 to 1, but mine is totally different.
Here is my code.

```
import sys
import jax
import time
from jax import grad
import seaborn as sns
from jax import random
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from jax.example_libraries import optimizers

n = 1000
params = [
    random.normal(random.PRNGKey(int(time.time())),(n,1)),
    jnp.zeros((n,1)),
    jnp.ones((n,1))
    ]

def forward(params, x):
    [mu, sigma, weight] = params
    z    = (stats.norm.cdf(x, mu, jnp.exp(sigma))*jax.nn.softmax(weight)).mean(axis=0)
    dzdx = (stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, jnp.exp(sigma))*jax.nn.softmax(weight)).mean(axis=0)
    return z, jnp.log(dzdx)

def likelihood(params, x):
    z, dzdx = forward(params, x)
    return -( jnp.log(stats.uniform.pdf(z)) + dzdx ).mean()

opt_init, opt_update, get_params = optimizers.adam(1e-1)
opt_state = opt_init(params)
l = []
for i in range(100):
    seed = random.PRNGKey(int(time.time()))
    key = random.split(seed,2)
    x     = random.normal(key[0],(n,))*0.9 - 3.1
    
    loss, grad = jax.value_and_grad(likelihood)(get_params(opt_state), x )
    opt_state = opt_update(1, grad, opt_state)
    l.append(loss)
    
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.write("[%-100s] %d%%" % ('='*i, i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    
fig0 = plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(l)

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
x_line = jnp.linspace(-7,7,n)
z,dzdx = forward(get_params(opt_state), x_line)
plt.hist(z, bins=50, color = 'red')
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
# plt.scatter(x_line,z, color = 'blue')
sns.distplot(x, color = 'green')
px = jnp.exp(jnp.log(stats.uniform.pdf(z))+dzdx)
plt.plot(x_line, px, color = 'black')
```

I am trying to fix the z distribution with my forward function like the video shows. Because my gradient part has been exploiting in the later section which I am doing right now.
I want someone to help me to fix the problem. I think the problem is some characteristics of python. But I do not know how to reach that, this video shows the math, I think that is good enough to start.

Comment: This question is far too open-ended to expect a real answer, but looking at your code I notice two things: (1) some of your arrays are shape `(n, 1)`, and others are shape `(n,)`. When you do operations on them, it's implicitly broadcasting to `(n, n)`, which is likely not what you want. (2) your key initialization strategy is flawed: you are using `random.PRNGKey(int(time.time()))` in a loop that takes less than a second per iteration, and so sequential seeds are identical, which likely biases your results.